Without upgrading sitecore version 10.2,how can i update current Solr version 8.8.2
Without upgrading Sitecore current version 10.2, How can I update the current Solr version 8.8.2?
Do we have an alternate to fix the Vulnerabilities?

It is not recommended to upgrade Solr version with respect to compatibility issue. You can follow any of the following steps to solve Solr vulnerability issue without upgrade.

Manually update the version of Log4J on your runtime classpath and restart your Solr application.

In case Solr is hosted on Linux/MacOS, you can edit solr.in.sh file to include below command.


SOLR_OPTS="$SOLR_OPTS -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true"

Whereas in case Solr is hosted on Window, edit solr.in.cmd file to include below command.
set SOLR_OPTS=%SOLR_OPTS% -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true

You can refer below documentation for more details on mitigation of vulnerability issue.
https://solr.apache.org/security.html#apache-solr-affected-by-apache-log4j-cve-2021-44228
Hope this helps!!!

Upgrade of Solr version approach is not available for compatibility reasons in Sitecore.
For reference, you can find Solr compatibility table here.
You should manually modify affected components of Solr Service-

You need to manually update the version of Log4J on your runtime
For Windows, Edit your solr.in.cmd file to include: set SOLR_OPTS=%SOLR_OPTS% -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true

Sitecore has already released below security bulletin to resolve this problem.
https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1001391
Hope this helps !
